# What is process com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0?

Tags: android, google-chrome, memory-management, admob, chromium

I have an Android app with one process and an always running service, on checking the running service I saw that my app has two running processes one for me and the other from chrome called "com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0" , Anyone knows why this service is running inside my app?, I am thinking of Google Admob but I am not sure.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you find the issue? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you running any webview inside your app.
From android O onwards, webview rendering happens on a different process. The separate process should be the one which is handling your webview.

Comment: No, I don't have any webviews at all,